# Can Queries To the Chain be made From Plutus Smart Contracts?

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, cardano-cli, cardano-node, on-chain, smart-contract

Considering that Plutus Smart Contracts have two parts (on chain and off chain) is there a way to make Queries to the Cardano Chain in the onchain part of the contract considering that the SC is actually already on the chain?

I want to be able to look up the transaction history of an address and check its balance.

I know I can do this via the Cardano Node, but considering that the contract must run on the node this should be possible how do I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reaching out to the Plutus-core team I got the answer and paraphrased it here.

They can but the functionality is quite limited right now, as the module is still under development. This means that it is likely unsafe for real applications.

I suggest waiting for the next stable update to plutus.

EDIT:

As per @kindofdev request, the module is the request module. I offered to help the team improve and build it out. Hope they agree. Anyone reading this is advised to urge them to let me build part of it.

Comment: Can you please pinpoint the module?

Comment: where's the proposal/issue?

Answer (score 2):

The way I understood things from last Q&A session with Lars, no, you can't. You can only see the current transaction, not the history of an address.

Comment: This is incorrect the module call exist. See nest post, but its all in monads.